# Finding the big circle from partial arc of the circle. (from crescent, draw full moon.)

Tags: python, opencv

Thank you guys. Poorly, I know just a few cv2 functions, not that good yet.;;;

There is an image of thick arc, it may looks like dull crescent moon.
Using the Python and CV2, I have to draw a circle based on that arc.
[image: img01.png]

I coded like below, and it works good.
(Find contours > Target the largest > Find fitEllipse > Draw small arc on short radius opposite > minEnclosingCircle including contour and the small arc.)
[image: img03.png]
But I feel fragile, incomplete... There must be better way. isn't it?

Could you help me to improve this code?

```
import cv2, numpy, pylab as plt
## load the image, and binarize.  
image_read = cv2.imread('img01.png')
gray_canvas = cv2.cvtColor(image_read, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
t_, gray_canvas = cv2.threshold(gray_canvas, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) #cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
canvas_size = gray_canvas.shape
plt.imshow(gray_canvas)
plt.show()

## contours on new canvas, and focus on the largest.  
c_list, h_list = cv2.findContours(gray_canvas, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
pxs_list = []
for c_ in c_list: pxs_list.append(cv2.contourArea(c_))
my_c = c_list[numpy.argmax(pxs_list)]
e_canvas = numpy.zeros(canvas_size, dtype=numpy.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(e_canvas, [my_c], -1, (255,255,255), 1)
plt.imshow(e_canvas)
plt.show()

## find the fitEllipse and large circle ...  
my_e = cv2.fitEllipse(my_c)
e_center = (int(my_e[0][0]), int(my_e[0][1]))
e_radii = (int(my_e[1][0]), int(my_e[1][1]))
e_deg = int(my_e[-1])
cv2.ellipse(e_canvas, my_e, (255,255,255), 3) # Draw an ellipse (option for eyes, not necessary).  
cv2.line(e_canvas, e_center, e_center, (128,128,128), 10) # Draw a point (option for eyes, not necessary).  
cv2.ellipse(e_canvas, e_center, e_radii, e_deg+90, 80, 100, (255,255,255), 3) # Put a little arc. essential.  
c2_list, h2_list = cv2.findContours(e_canvas, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
m_center, m_radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(numpy.vstack(c2_list))
cv2.circle(e_canvas, (int(m_center[0]), int(m_center[1])), int(m_radius), (255,255,255), 3)
plt.imshow(e_canvas)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Use finite differences to compute first and second derivatives from the outer contour edge. Then compute the radius of curvature.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference